# Python Requests Module - How to download an mp4 behind a login page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, download

I have an mp4 on a website that I want to download using Python's Requests module. The problem is that each mp4 url is behind a login page. For example, if you go to the url in my code, it requires that one signs into their account before being able to access the mp4 directly.

Is there any way to go about downloading mp4s like this easily? It's ok if I need users to log into their account before being able to download it, but I'm unsure about how to take this into account with Python. Thanks.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
import requests

chunk_size = 256

url = "https://juilliard.hosted.panopto.com/Panopto/Pages/Embed.aspx?id=f290a855-c462-4406-a965-af2700f259fe&remoteEmbed=true&remoteHost=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.juilliard.edu&embedApiId=panopto-video-player"

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

with open("performance.mp4", "wb") as f:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
        f.write(chunk)
```